# How to set all boxes collapsed in adminlte?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, adminlte

I have a collapsible box in adminlte. by default when page loads, it's expanded. How to make it collapsed by default?

Here is what I have used to make box:

https://adminlte.io/docs/2.4/js-box-widget

My HTML:

```
<div class="box">

  <div class="box-header with-border">

    <h3 class="box-title">Collapsible Box Example</h3>

    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
      <!-- Collapse Button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="box-body">
    The body of the box
  </div>

  <div class="box-footer">
    The footer of the box
  </div>

</div>
```

My script:

```
<script>
$('.box').boxWidget({
    animationSpeed: 500,
    collapseTrigger: '#my-collapse-button-trigger',
    removeTrigger: '#my-remove-button-trigger',
    collapseIcon: 'fa-minus',
    expandIcon: 'fa-plus',
    removeIcon: 'fa-times',
    hide: true
})
```

Comment: You can do all of your collapse in HTML without the script much easier. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/ for some examples.

Comment: Thanks but I want to use adminlte box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`boxWidget('collapse')`](https://adminlte.io/docs/2.4/js-box-widget)

```
$('.box').boxWidget({
    animationSpeed: 500,
    collapseTrigger: '#my-collapse-button-trigger',
    removeTrigger: '#my-remove-button-trigger',
    collapseIcon: 'fa-minus',
    expandIcon: 'fa-plus',
    removeIcon: 'fa-times',
    hide: true
})

$('.box').boxWidget('collapse')
```

**OR** add `collapsed-box` class

```
<div class="box collapsed-box">
 ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add `collapsed-box` `class` to `<div class="box">`.

Then, add `display: none` `inline style` to `<div class="box-body">` and `<div class="box-footer">`.

Like this:

```
<div class="box collapsed-box">
   <div class="box-header with-border">
      <h3 class="box-title">Collapsible Box Example</h3>
      <div class="box-tools pull-right">
         <!-- Collapse Button -->
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
         <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="box-body" style="display: none">
      The body of the box
   </div>
   <!-- /.box-body -->
   <div class="box-footer" style="display: none">
      The footer of the box
   </div>
</div>
```

It should work.